# what is the path for libcudart.so?

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, gpu, tensorflow, nvidia

I'm trying to install Tensorflow GPU version and I'm stuck at this.
I've installed nvidia-cuda-toolkit by running

```
 sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

and it downloaded fine. But i'm unable to locate this libcudart.so

```
Please specify which gcc nvcc should use as the host compiler. [Default is /usr/bin/gcc]: /usr/bin/gcc
Please specify the Cuda SDK version you want to use, e.g. 7.0. [Leave empty to use system default]: 
Please specify the location where CUDA  toolkit is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: /usr/local/cuda
Invalid path to CUDA  toolkit. /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so cannot be found
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you install Cuda 7.5 manually from NVidia website, you'll have it at `usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so`

Comment: I've libcudnn files there, but there is no libcudart.so

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
locate libcudart.so
```

if nothing is found, update the cache with `sudo updatedb` and try again.

Answer (score 3):

According to apt-file, libcudart is installed in:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

This is for Ubuntu 14.04. Since you didn't put in details of your system, I assumed you were using Ubuntu since you were using apt. The CUDA installer from nvidia's website defaults the installation location to

```
/usr/local/cuda-7.0
```

with a symlink to

```
/usr/local/cuda
```

That's why the installer defaulted to /usr/local/cuda

Comment: I tagged Xubuntu, i recently upgraded to 16.04

Comment: I'd suggest you use the Nvidia installer rather than the pre-rolled package from Debian/apt. I understand the appeal of "sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit" but most people (and therefore tutorials) seem to assume the installation directory is /usr/local.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be in

```
/usr/local/cuda/lib64/
```

If you are using anaconda, then you can search it in

```
$ANACONDA_PATH/envs/$ENV_NAME/lib/
```